# How to set timer for a search value

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send a search value after complete searching for example after 10 sec as the below code for `onTextChanged` method:

```
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
//                searchEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Config.sendToMixpanel(Config.MIXPANEL_EVENT_SEARCH + charSequence, mMixpanel);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, 10000);


            }
```

it send to the mixpanel multiple times, I want send to mix panel after finishing search the complete searched word and it sent to the mix panel as the below image:

[image]
I need to send one time only..

This is the below `sendToMixPanel()`:

```
    //Send the Event to Mix Panel Method
    public static void sendToMixpanel(String logEventName, MixpanelAPI mMixpanelApi) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject props = new JSONObject();
        props.put("source", "Pat's affiliate site");
        props.put("Opted out of email", true);
        mMixpanelApi.track(logEventName, props);
    }
```

and this is the below search activity:

```
package com.quantatil.ikhair.UILayer.Activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI;
import com.quantatil.ikhair.App.Config;
import com.quantatil.ikhair.R;
import com.quantatil.ikhair.UILayer.Fragments.SearchQueryFragment;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class SearchActivity extends BaseActivity {


    @BindView(R.id.search_input)
    EditText searchEditText;
    @BindView(R.id.delete_search_query)
    View deleteSearchQuery;
    SearchQueryFragment searchQueryFragment;

    private MixpanelAPI mMixpanel;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        mMixpanel = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(this, Config.MIXPANEL_API_TOKEN);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        searchQueryFragment = new SearchQueryFragment();
        showFragment(searchQueryFragment);
        setupSearchTextWatcher();
    }


    private void setupSearchTextWatcher() {
        searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
//                searchEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
//                searchEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Config.sendToMixpanel(Config.MIXPANEL_EVENT_SEARCH + charSequence, mMixpanel);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, 10000);


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                String query = searchEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (deleteSearchQuery.getVisibility() != View.INVISIBLE && TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
                    deleteSearchQuery.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    deleteSearchQuery.setClickable(false);
                    searchQueryFragment.clear();
                } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {

                    if (deleteSearchQuery.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                        deleteSearchQuery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        deleteSearchQuery.setClickable(true);
                    }
                    searchQueryFragment.search(searchQueryFragment, query);

                }
            }
        });
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.delete_search_query)
    void deleteSearchQuery() {
        searchEditText.setText("");
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.back_icon)
    void backClicked() {
        onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

the timer works fine but send the value multiple times, want just send one time only..

#Edited

I tried to add the timer method in the button I need as the below code:

```
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    CharSequence charSequence;

    @OnClick(R.id.search_icon)
    void startSearch(){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , SearchActivity.class));
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Config.sendToMixpanel(Config.MIXPANEL_EVENT_SEARCH + charSequence, mMixpanel);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },10000);
```

It gives me with a search value with null but it sends it one time only as the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Handler's postDelayed() method, and pass in a Runnable task. Example:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do your work here after 10s
    }
}, 10000);
```

EDIT:

In your code it would be something like this:

```
public class SearchActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.search_input)
    EditText searchEditText;
    ...

    private MixpanelAPI mMixpanel;

    private CharSequence myCharSequence;
    private final Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }

    ...
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            myCharSequence = charSequence;
        }
    ...

    @OnClick(R.id.search_icon)
    void startSearch(){
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Config.sendToMixpanel(Config.MIXPANEL_EVENT_SEARCH + myCharSequence, mMixpanel);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 10000);
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , SearchActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I would like to let you know that It gives me the same result

Comment: You're right, sorry. You're calling this in onTextChanged(), so whenever text changes, this method will be invoked, and therefore execute handler as well. You should move you're call to somewhere else (e.g. if you have a button to start search, you can put it in the button's onClick callback).

Comment: I have edited my post by adding the method inside the button it gives a value with a null

Comment: Because you're not assigning anything to charSequence variable that you're sending. You should declare charSequence at start of the class, then in onTextChanged assign value to charSequence, and then on button onClick do sendToMixPanel().

Comment: I tried what exactly you said I found the same problem it gives me with value for null, could you let me know more how can I implement this related to my code ones :)

Comment: btw. declare `Handler handler` on top of the file and before setting `postDelayed` `Runnable` call `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages()` for removing previously set and avoiding multiple API calls

Comment: Edited comment to add example code based on what you provided. you should also do timer/handler operation before starting another activity.